# In SQL Server, how to reduce the number of columns displayed when using Select Top 1000 Rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I used Select Top 1000 Rows function (right click on a table) on one of the tables in our database, it only displayed 10 columns. However, when I used `SELECT * FROM ...`, all 17 columns would display.

This phenomenon doesn't seem to happen to any other tables. We have one table with over 150 columns, which are all displayed utilizing Select Top 1000 Rows function. And our DBA is on holiday, so does anybody know how this is achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably best to post the sql. Did you list all 17 columns in the select clause? Are the columns not appearing at all or just producing null values? Top generally has no effect on the choice of columns returned.

Comment: The SQL statement was `Select Top 1000 Rows`? What "it" displayed 10 columns? What is your DBA celebrating?

Comment: Select Top 1000 Rows is not a valid statement

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 ROWS is valid sql if you are retrieving a column named "ROWS". Presumably the SQL is something like SELECT TOP 1000 * or SELECT TOP 1000 firstName,lastNam,age

Comment: It's possible the account you're connecting as doesn't have select permissions for every column in the table in question. @ all it's a fair assumption that 'Select Top 1000 rows' in this case is referring to the right-click menu option in object explorer & the query it generates for you.

Comment: I tried editing to guess what you want but can you share the `SQL`, please?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I should describe more clearly in my description. Gareth Lyons is right, I was using "Select Top 1000 Rows" function by right clicking the table. By default, this should only reduce the rows but display all the columns. I have select permissions to every columns, as I can see them when I use 'Select * From ...'. Our DBA is just celebrating New Year holiday...

Comment: @joshp That is not a valid statement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible in general.

It happens by design when the table contains `SPARSE` columns which presumably explains your 17->10 example.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T1  
    (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    C1 INT SPARSE NULL,
    C2 INT SPARSE NULL,
    C3 INT SPARSE NULL
    )
```

And then using the `SELECT TOP 1000 Rows` option generates this.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
  FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[T1]
```

You can delete the column list and just drag the columns folder over to get the full list though.

[image]

In your case I believe you want the opposite. **Don't change the columns to sparse to get this behaviour!** You can create a view with the subset of the  150 columns that you are interested in seeing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The extra columns are all `SPARSE` by design because they have a lot of `NULL` values. Thank you.